# I can't see wordpress strength indicator and 'hide' pw button is not working

Tags: html, wordpress

[image]

I'm trying to make registration page using HTML template. The problem is that 
I can't see wordpress strength indicator and 'hide' pw button is not working.
How can I fix these problems?
Is it because wordpress basic funcions are not loaded while I'm trying to put it into the HTML template?
Please help

```
<p><?php _e( 'Strength indicator', APP_TD ); ?></p>
<p><?php _e( 'Hint: The password should be at least seven characters long.
 To make it stronger, use upper and lower case letters, numbers and symbols                        
 like ! " ? $ % ^ &amp; ).', APP_TD ); ?></p>

<button type="button" class="button secondary small wp-hide-pw hide-if-no-     
js" data-start-masked="<?php echo (int) isset( $_POST['pass1'] ); ?>" data-  
toggle="0" aria-label="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Hide password', APP_TD ); ?>">
<span class="dashicons dashicons-hidden"></span>
<span class="text"><?php _e( 'Hide', APP_TD ); ?></span>
</button>
```